# How do I compare the size of a file passed as an argument to a number of megabytes?

Tags: bash

I have a script that uses a file or directory as an argument and I want to compare THAT file to an arbitrary number of MEGABYTES to see if the file is greater than, less than or equal to 1 MEGABYTE.

What I think the answer is:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$1 
export FILE1 

if [ -f$1 ];

then  
        echo "Hello world!" 

fi 

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then 
       echo "This file is less than 1 megabyte"
fi
```

I'm trying to pass this file as an argument and see if it has less than one megabyte. Now, I need to know if $# -lt 1 is actually less than 1 megabyte or less than an integer of 1.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... Do you mean receive a file name as argument and check whether the file has less than 1 megabyte in size? Or check the length of an argument and check whether the argument itself has a length of less than a megabyte? (Note that arguments of a megabyte or more of length are highly unusual!) Please update your question to clarify what exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well filipe, I'm passing a file as an argument and seeing if this file I'm passing as an argument is less than 1 megabyte. But, I need to know if the code I wrote actually compares to the actual megabyte size or just the integer number 1.

Comment: You're using `$#` which returns the number of arguments passed to the script, and has nothing to do with the size of the file passed as an argument.

Comment: You can use the [stat(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) command to find the size of a file given its path.

In your example, taking a file path as argument:

    `filesize=$(stat --format=%s "$1")`. I hope this helps... Try to rephrase your question, you might get a better answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some commenters / answerers have said, your script isn't acquiring the size of the file that's passed in. You'll need to do that in order to compare it to a megabyte.

One option is the `stat` command:

```
bytes=$(stat -c %s filename_here)
```

Another option is the `wc` command:

```
bytes=$(wc -c < filename_here)
```

Next, you want to compare it to one megabyte; bash arithmetic is limited to integers, so attempting to compare to fractional numbers is doomed to failure. Instead, compare to 1048576 bytes.

Wrapping it up, it could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f "$1" ];
then  
  echo "Hello world!"
  bytes=$(stat -c %s "$1")
  if [ "$bytes" -lt 1048576 ]; then 
    echo "This file is less than 1 megabyte"
  fi
fi
```

I moved the size-counting inside of the first `if` statement; there's no point in checking the size of a file that doesn't exist. Also, unless you're doing something else with the arguments, there's no real need to use another variable name, so I just kept using `$1`.

Comment: Jeff, did this print for you? Because it does not print for me. It literally prints nothing.

Comment: Did you pass it a file that exists?

Comment: OOOOOOOO so I have to use helloworld.sh as an argument, dude!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have logical and syntax errors in your script.

- you assign `FILE` and export `FILE1` (doesn't hurt but doesn't make sense either).
- you don't use neither `FILE` nor `FILE1` any more (same).
- you need a space between the "conditional primary" and the filename in `[ -f$1 ]`
- the `$#` yields the script's argument count, not a file size (as already pointed out by Filipe Brandenburger)
- you need an alternative info source, on top of the mentined `stat` you could use `du -b file`

Comment: understood, thanks. I just fixed my code up and when I do if [ $1 -lt 1] I get an error, the interpreter expects a unary operator when I call ./helloworld.sh myfile. How can I fix this?

Comment: a) get rid of syntax error:  `[ $1 -lt 1]` needs a space before closing square bracket. b) `-lt` is an "integer operator" - how do you expect it to work on the "myfile" string? What exactly do you want to achieve, and how? How do the hints you received NOT let you get to the solution required?

Comment: I already told you what I wanted to achieve. Compare a file passed as an argument to 1. -lt is an integer operator? Okay, so how do I compare without using an integer operator? Are there other comparison operators in bash I can use?